# How Do I only Click on Certain Number of URL Links Using Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, loops

Noob question (1 month of coding):

I wanted to limit the number of videos clicked to only the first 3 (arbitrary number) videos.

I am able to run the code successfully but it will click on all videos. I'm ok with all the videos being opened in new tabs but I was just wondering if there was a way to limit the number of videos being opened.

I tried using loops but was unsuccessful.

Thanks in advance.

'''

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


# open URL
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/user/MegatoadStonie/videos'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)


# click on videos
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@id='video-title']")
for x in links:
    x.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.ENTER)
```

'''

Comment: What if instead of `for x in links`, you write `for x in links[:3]`?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! That did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing

```py
for x in links:
    x.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.ENTER)
```

you can write

```py
for x in links[:3]:
    x.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.ENTER)
```

This way instead of opening all the links, we open the first three links.

`links[:3]` is a sublist of `links` with the 0th through 2nd element of the `links` array. You can learn more about Python array slicing here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/5139284

Comment: Thanks for the reference link. There's a lot of helpful information there.

Comment: @David If this resolved your problem, please upvote it and mark it as an accepted answer by clicking the check mark